SharePoint metadata column limitations - how to understand them
I am not sure if I correctly understand those limits:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#managed-metadata
Let me firstly describe the challenge:
We would like to make a SharePoint as the main storage for files where we want to heavily use Metadata columns. The access to the SP would be provided by custom APP with PnP Core SDK. (No direct access to SP). Right now we are checking the limits and we do not quite understand them.
Let assume that we have dedicated Site for the integration. Then those limits related to the managed metadata (url above) would work like this?

Each document contains 20 custom metadata columns so having those 2 million labels limitation we can store only 100 000 files? Is that correct? Or I missing something here?


The limit of 2 million labels per site collection for managed metadata refers to the total number of unique terms that can be used across all term sets in the site collection. It does not directly limit the number of files that can have custom metadata columns. However, the limit of 50,000 unique permissions for items in a list or library may impact the number of custom metadata columns that can be used effectively. Additionally, the recommended limit of 50 terms as default on a managed metadata column may also impact the number of custom metadata columns that can be used effectively.
